# Is it possible to restrict access of certain members of a class to another class but not all other classes?

Tags: java, inheritance

For example I have Class A, Class B, Class C
Class A has 5 instance variables.
Both class B and C extend class A.
Is it possible for class B to have access to all the members and class C have access to only 2 of the members? provided that they are in the same package.

Comment: No, it's not possible. You may want to redesign your classes. Or _just don't use_ the "prohibited" members from class C.

Comment: No, that goes against the whole point of inheritance and smells of poor design.

Comment: I'd like to see more about what you're trying to accomplish.  Also, if `C` is in the same package, why do you want to restrict access to three of the members--as opposed to just self-restraint?  Are you concerned about someone else later modifying the class and messing something up?  Unlike some, I'm not willing to pronounce that this is a "poor design" without seeing details--I could envision that this could be a legitimate design in some situation.  But I'd want to see more information.

Comment: Ah, this is homework?  Well then never mind my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is sort of possible. Make 3 of the fields `private` and make `B` a `static` nested class of `A`. Then `B` has access to all members of `A` if you cast to an `A`. Like this:

```
public class A {

    private int a = 1;
    private int b = 2;
    private int c = 3;
    int d = 4;
    int e = 5;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new B().test();
    }

    private static class B extends A {

        private void test() {
            System.out.println(((A) this).a);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That seemed like it would work, so I tried it. The static inner subclass still doesn't have access to the private instance variable of its outer superclass. This is in Java7.